# Getting files from directory-Python, Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, directory, beautifulsoup

I am writing a parsing code in Python, that takes html pages and extracts certain information.
My html's are stored in a a doc called filelist.txt and in a directory called rawdata.
My current method for getting the files looks like this:

```
def getfiles(foldername):

    infile = "filelist.txt"
    infileh = open(infile, "r")
    onlyfiles = []
    for line in infileh:
            onlyfiles.append(line.strip())

    #print onlyfiles                                                                            
    #onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(foldername) if isfile(join(foldername,f)) ]               
    return onlyfiles
```

and:

```
filepath ="/mnt/nfs6/wikipedia.proj/odesk/rawdata/" + filename
    #print filepath                                                                             
    filehandle = open(filepath, "r")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle)
```

But now I need to change my method: the files are not all located in one big file text- rather they are in many separate directories- and I would like my code to loop through each directory and grab the files and run the code on them.
I am not confused so much by how to loop but rather how to write the 'getfiles' method to go into a non-specific directory.
Can anyone suggest a way or direct me to information where I could learn more about this? (I'm using python, Beautiful Soup, and os)

Answer (score 0):

You might find os.walk useful to walk through a directory structure from a given starting point. You can then test each file found against whatever conditions you need to before appending it to your list:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

[os.path.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) is the `find` of python. Other methods in `os.path` like `listdir` will be useful.